# 'Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jemoji"' when bundle exec jekyll serve

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundler

Actually I don't quite know what bundle nor jekyll is , but I am trying to execute `bundle exec jekyll serve` follow the guide https://github.com/apache/incubator-rocketmq-site , but fails.

I can't find google something similar like this so I post a question here.

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:21                                                                                       8:in `rescue in start': Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jemo                                                                                       ji": (Bundler::VersionConflict)
  In Gemfile:
    minimal-mistakes-jekyll x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      jemoji (~> 0.7) x64-mingw32

Could not find gem 'jemoji (~> 0.7) x64-mingw32', which is required by gem 'mini                                                                                       mal-mistakes-jekyll x64-mingw32', in any of the sources.
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/r                                                                                       esolver.rb:212:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/r                                                                                       esolver.rb:191:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/d                                                                                       efinition.rb:235:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/d                                                                                       efinition.rb:159:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/d                                                                                       efinition.rb:218:in `specs_for'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/d                                                                                       efinition.rb:207:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/r                                                                                       untime.rb:109:in `block in definition_method'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/r                                                                                       untime.rb:21:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.r                                                                                       b:101:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/s                                                                                       etup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54                                                                                       :in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54                                                                                       :in `require'
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `bundle install` alone first (step 4 in the linked README). This should install the necessary packages.

Then you can run `bundle exec jekyll serve`. The `bundle exec` means it will use those installed packages.

Comment: Thank you! I find that my bundle install is failed! I have resolve it and the problem then disappears.